# Не подгружаются ресурсы

Tags: php, laravel

Использую Laravel 5, шаблонизатор blade. 
Пытаюсь подгрузить ресурс css следующим образом:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

Файлик лежит в public/css. Работает все корректно только по адресу informaticege/index.php , а без index.php (informaticege) не прописывается каталог public и поэтому не включаются стили. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: А маршруты вообще верно обрабатывает ? может сервер не настроен ? проверял сели через php artisan serve запускаешь все ок ?

Comment: После установки был index of со всеми файлами. В корень добавил .htaccess со следующим содержимым:   

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

Comment: не это понятно, нужно понять сервер у вас верно настроен или нет, может он base_path странно отрабатывает

Comment: Выполнил php artisan serve : Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/

Comment: Ну перейдите, на этот адресс :) работает или так же все плохо

Comment: Да, все отлично работает! Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

`<link href="{{ url('/') }}/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Поясните свой ответ, пожалуйста - где конкретно автор ошибся, как это было исправлено, как этого избежать в будущем. Не лишними будут ссылки на документацию.

Comment: К сожалению, сейчас уже не найду. 
Просто сталкивался с такой проблемой. Решение нашел такое.

Кстати. Вот еще одно решение.
https://medium.com/@zwacky/laravels-url-to-vs-url-asset-fd427ed6f7ef#.p09uhw56m

Работоспособность его не проверял